# Function time its own gradient and vector scalar its divergence

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-operator

I wanted to make sure of something, I know that for any function $f$ we have $ff'= \frac{1}{2}(f^2)'$. Then do we have the same principle for the gradient and divergence operators ?
Lets take $f$ a function and $\vec{g}$ a vector, do we have the equalities below for any coordinates (spherical, cylindrical?...):
$$ f \vec{\nabla}f \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{2}\vec{\nabla}f^2$$
$$\vec{g}.(\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{g}) \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{2} \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{g^2}$$
and if so does someone have a proof of it or where I could find one ? Because for the first one with the gradient I think this is true but I have big doubts for the one with the divergence.
Thanks

Comment: How are you defining $g^2$?

Comment: Well that's mainly the point of my question for the divergence and instead of $g^2$ it could maybe be : $\vec{g} \times \vec{g}$

Comment: But still is it correct for the gradient ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
$

Let $\bullet_s : \R\times\R \to \R$ and $\bullet_v : \R^n\times\R^n \to \R^n$ be *commutative* products on vectors. A general fact is that *the derivative of an expression is the sum of the derivatives of its parts*. For $\bullet_s$ and a function $f : \R^n \to \R$ this looks like
$$
  \nabla(f\bullet_s f)
    = \dot\nabla(\dot f\bullet_s f) + \dot\nabla(f\bullet_s\dot f)
    = 2\dot\nabla(\dot f\bullet_s f).
\tag{1}
$$
The notation $\dot\nabla$ means that we are *only* differentiating $\dot f$, and the undotted $f$ should be thought of as constant while differentiating. An example of a more verbose notation would be
$$
  \dot\nabla(\dot f\bullet_s f) = \bigl[\nabla_y(f(y)\bullet_s f(x))\bigr]_{y=x}.
$$
When $\bullet_s$ is just multiplication, then (1) gives
$$
  \nabla f^2 = 2(\nabla f)f = 2f\nabla f.
$$

Similarly, when considering $\bullet_v$ and $g : \R^n \to \R^n$ we get
$$
  \nabla\cdot(g\bullet_v g)
    = \dot\nabla\cdot(\dot g\bullet_v g) + \dot\nabla\cdot(g\bullet_v\dot g)
    = 2\dot\nabla\cdot(\dot g\bullet_v g).
\tag{2}
$$
I stress that this requires that $\bullet_v$ is *commutative*; if it is *anti*-commutative like the cross product when $n=3$, a similar derivation to (2) shows that $\nabla\cdot(g\times g) = 0$, as it should since $g\times g = 0$.

The nice thing about the $\dot\nabla$ notation is that it can be treated like a generic vector; any identity that hold for all vectors will also hold when that vector replaced with $\dot\nabla$. So we could say that the reason $\dot\nabla(\dot ff) = f\nabla f$ works is because for any vector $v$ and scalars $a, b$
$$
  v(ab) = b(va)
$$
so replacing $v$ with $\dot\nabla$, $a$ with $\dot f$, and $b$ with $f$ gives the desired result.

We can use this idea to try to get what you want with $\bullet_v$. However, your equation $g(\nabla\cdot g) = \tfrac12\nabla\cdot g^2$ doesn't make sense as it stands, since the LHS is a vector but the RHS is a scalar.
What we'll consider instead is trying to make true
$$
  \nabla\cdot(g\bullet_v g) = 2F(g)(\nabla\cdot g)
\tag{3}
$$
where is $F : \R^n \to \R$ and $F(g)$ is $F(g(x))$ with the $x$ dependence suppressed. A sufficient condition is for the following identity on vectors $u,v,w$ to hold:
$$
  u\cdot(v\bullet_v w) = F(w)(u\cdot v).
$$
This fully determines $v\bullet_v w$. Choose $u = e_i$ where $e_i$ is the $i^\text{th}$ standard basis element, multiply by $e_i$, and sum over $i$. This gives
$$
  v\bullet_v w
    = F(w)\sum_{i=1}^n(e_i\cdot v)e_i
    = F(w)v.
$$
We need this to be commutative, so
$$
  F(w)v - F(v)w = 0,
$$
But this is impossible unless $F(v) = 0$ for all $v$, since we can simply choose $v$ and $w$ to be linearly independent. (In the case $n=1$ we can choose $F(v) = v$, and $\bullet_v$ and the dot product $\cdot$ are just multiplication.) This suggests (though does not prove) that there is no non-trivial product $\bullet_v$ taking vectors to vectors satisfying (3).

Comment: Wow ok thank you for your developed question and your time. So to put it in a nutshell I was 'right' for the gradient but it is more complicated for the divergence operator because we are dealing with vectors ?

Comment: @Michael Yes, I think that is a fair assessment.

Comment: Amazing, thanks again